# Getting user input in a while loop

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a basic IRC by using Kryonet for communication. The problem I am having is that in my code, I cannot safely have a main while loop that allows the user to type and send a message, because Scanner gives an error and appears to skip past the call to nextLine(). What I want to do is have the Scanner wait for user input before continuing.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (running){

        System.out.print(":");

        message.text = input.nextLine();

        client.sendTCP(message);

    }

    input.close();
```

To be more precise, the program will first put a ":" at the beginning of the line, and then will get whatever the user types after they press enter, and then send that off to the server.
Here's the error I'm getting:

```
:Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at com.andrewlalisofficial.ChatClient.main(ChatClient.java:51)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are closing `System.in` (through `Scanner`) - don't do that. If you close it and then try to read from it again with a new `Scanner`, it will throw the exception you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true){
    System.out.print(":");
    String text = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

This is working here.